# How to show result without category ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have categories 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

How to show all results from table 'news' without category 3..?

tnx.

```
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`content` longtext NOT NULL,
`category` int(20) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: SELECT * FROM news WHERE id != 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple just simply use `!= 3`.

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE category != 3
```

Comment: That really should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do the condition where category!='3' inside the query

You can use `$cat_id` for storing any category excluding from the result.

```
$cat_id = 3;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE category!='$cat_id'";
$qry = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($qry) > 0)
{
  while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry))
  {
   // Do the action
  }
}
```